# I want to loop every text in a div .each(function() - jquery

Tags: jquery

I have these URLs from a text file

```
"http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xom.sssss/data/feed/base/user/592591?kind\u003doium\u00flt\u065drss\u002s\u0asn_7S\udess\aawac", "url": 

"http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xom.sssss/data/feed/base/user/592591?kind\u003doium\u00flt\u065drss\u002s\u0asn_7S\udess\aawac", "url":  }, 

"http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xom.sssss/data/feed/base/user/592591?kind\u003doium\u00flt\u065drss\u002s\u0asn_7S\udess\aawac", "url":
```

I want to do a loop, in #from and append it to #here

```
$('#from').match(/http:\/\/\S+/).each(function(){;
    var t = $(this).text();
    $(t).appendTo('#here');
});
```

There seems to be an error .

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="from">

<? 
$fl = "file.txt"; 
$file1 = fopen($fl, "r");
$content = file_get_contents($fl); 
echo $content;       
?>

</div>

<div id="here"></div>
```

I could easily use PHP, but I want it to make it in jQuery, since it gives me the freedom to pull any http://, be it anywhere in the text file or how complicated it may be.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: What does your HTML look like? `.match` only works on strings, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Can you post what the markup looks like?

Comment: @Jean: Artic refers to the first semicolon `function(){;`, which should simply be removed. it's not the cause of any of your problems, though

Comment: It looks like you have JSON data in a text file, did you paste the whole file as it seems to be lacking some data?

Comment: @tatu please consider it as a simple text file, since the data is going to be different, which is how I am writing the code.

Comment: @Jean: the data is malformated. that just looks like corrupted JSON. also, how do you get the content of this file to the javascript in the first place? and what is #from and #to? show us some of your html, and some more of your javascript.

Comment: @david I have provided the HTML code, please check

Comment: @Jean: alright, i've deleted my answer as it had nothing to do with what your actual question turned out to be. The data in file.txt still looks like malformed JSON. Are you 100% sure it's not *actual* JSON, that you've copied badly? Or supposed to be actual JSON? Because if the text can be treated as JSON, you can simply loop over that. Otherwise you'll have to use regex, something like cletus' answer, perhaps with some modification if that doesn't work immediately. everything you can do with javascript in regex, tho, you can also do, and more powerfully so, with regex in PHP. this doesn't...

Comment: ...look like a task for javascript at all.

Comment: @david, could I possibly have a solution?

Comment: @Jean: yes, possibly. since you say you "could easily use PHP", i'd say go for that, because in PHP, you still have " the freedom to pull any http://, be it anywhere in the text file or how complicated it may be." I'm not a PHP expert, tho, so I won't go into detail there. Regardless of whether you're doing it in PHP or JavaScript I'd look into whether the value of the text is actually a JSON string (or, if not, whether that could be fixed, because right now it just looks like malformed JSON). If it can be treated as JSON, you can loop over that in PHP or JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want what look like links from the *text* then do something like:

```
var text = $("#form").text();
var r = /\b(http://.*?)(?=\s|\z)/;
var here = $("#where");
while (m = r.exec(text)) {
  $("<span>").text(m[1]).appendTo("#here");
}
```

Your question is pretty vague about what you're dealing with and what you want the end result to be so I've made a lot of assumptions:

- This won't capture URLs in images or anchors.
- I don't know what the destination is or how (or even if) you want to wrap the URLs. In my example I'm just putting each in a `<span>`;
- I've been fairly liberal when it comes to interpreting what a URL is. I've assumed anything that starts on a word boundary with "http://" is a URL up to the end of the text or a white space character, whichever comes first. You can make this stricter if you wish.

Comment: @cletus
Error Message: Expected ')' in regular expression
From this line - var r = /\b(http://.*?)(?=\s|\z)/;

Comment: @Jean var r = /\b(http:\/\/.*?)(?=\s|\z)/;

Comment: @david hedlund
That is the line thats giving the error - Expected ')' in regular expression

Comment: @Jean: i corrected it. you won't get an error if you add the backslashes in the http part.

Comment: @david its the same
Your corrected answer: var r = /\b(http://.*?)(?=\s|\z)/;
Pre corrected answer: var r = /\b(http://.*?)(?=\s|\z)/;

Comment: @Jean: no, my corrected answer has backslashes in the http. Pre-corrected: `http://`, corrected: `http:\/\/`. The corrected version works. The pre-corrected one doesn't.

Comment: @david, its going into a loop, IE asks me to stop the script

Comment: @Jean: that may well be. i just corrected the regex so that it would compile. if it runs slow it's probably because the data does not look the way we expect it to, because you haven't described your situation very well. we still have no idea what #here and #from are, the little data you've shown looks corrupted, we haven't seen a single line of html, and you haven't *really* explained what you want to do, what you've tried, why that isn't working and what error message you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> I am trying to get all http links from #from and appending it to #here.

If I undestood you correctly, you need something like this:

```
$('#from a').appendTo('#here');
```

This will take all links (`<a>`-elements) from `#from` and move them to `#here`. Is this what you wanted?

If you don't want to move the links, but only copy them, you can use `.clone()`:

```
$('#from a').clone().appendTo('#here');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#from a[href^='http']").appendTo('#here')
```